# How can I open .zul file in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, zk, zul

I have downloaded the ZK plugin, but when I create a .zul file, it is just recognized as an unknown file for intellij. I tried resetting cache and rebooting, didn't make a difference..

Is there a way to connect the plugin to the extension? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Check the file types: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html#register-new-association .

Answer (score 0):

I had quite the opposite experience, I created a .zul file and IntelliJ automatically suggested something like: "There's a plugin available that handles .zul files, would you like to install download and it?" -> confirmed and restarted ... Then .zul files are registered as XML files under Settings/File Types and code completion is working.

Not sure how this is failing for you, can you provide your version details including the plugins installed?

Here what I am using (Help/About):

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-192.7142.36, built on October 29, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.4+10-b304.77 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-72-generic
...
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.zkoss.zkidea
```